# Dynamically append code to end of a function in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following JavaScript with some html. A sample demo can be found at following URL: http://js.do/sun21170/92329

My ambitious goal is to execute some code just after the `if else` part in `doSomething` function. *I have no control on what is inside this function since it's in a library I use* but I do want to execute some code after the last line of code is executed in this function.  So, it's like I want to dynamically insert some JavaScript code at end of `doSomething` function.

**Question**: Is it possible to dynamically insert some code after last line of code in `doSomething` function and if yes, then how would I do it?

For example, I want to insert following line of custom code: `alert(val);` or if accessing the variables is out-of-question then insert just some other custom code like `alert("hello");`. I tried getting the body of callback function and then I guess I could append my new code, but still cannot implement my very generic requirement.

```
<button type="button" onclick="callback(200);">Callback gets called </button>
<script>
var callback = null;
//the function below cannot be changed
function doSomething(val) {
    if (val > 150) {
        alert("You are not eligible for this reward");
    } else {
        alert("Congrats! You have just been rewarded");
    }
}


//set callback to something
callback = doSomething;

//I want to automatically execute some code when callback finishes execution without 
//having to explicitly write that code within the doSomething function OR
//writing code after doSomething function is called in onclick function of button
//If this is possible, HOW WOULD I IMPLEMENT THIS?


//I can get the body of a function using below code
function getCallBackBody(callbackFunction) {
    var entire = callbackFunction.toString();
    var body = entire.substring(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));
    return body;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're doing this because you need access to the variables within the function?  Or you just want code to run *after* the function, but without having to change the call to that function?

Comment: @James, I need this because I would like my custom code to run exactly when the last line in original callback finishes. So, it's not really necessary to access the variables inside the method. I have added this extra clarification to my original question. Thanks for making it more detailed to me.

Comment: No, this is not possible. However, you can replace/wrap said function if you have access to where it is stored so that you can override the one that the plugin/library is using.

Comment: @Kevin, You mean to physically replace that function in the library file?

Comment: @Sunil no, i mean replace it in the resulting object that the file creates on window. but... if you can't access the function from said object, there's a pretty good chance that you can't replace it either. In your simple example, replacing it would be as easy as creating a new global function with the same name.

Comment: @Kevin, I can override the function and just call the `callback(args);` as first line and then  add my custom code. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Basically, `function myFunction () { theirFunction(); myStuff();}` and you would then have to store `myFunction` wherever `theirFunction` was previously stored.

Comment: @KevinB, But if I do not want to access variables of original function, then I could put that new function anywhere and not necessarily in the library file in which `theirFunction` is stored?

Comment: depends. do you want it to affect times when the library calls it? or, only when you call it. or, does that even matter for the library you're using.

Comment: @KevinB, I want that  new function code to run every time the library method is called.

Comment: Then you'll have to replace it within the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace doSomething with a function that calls doSomething and then calls your code.  Make sure doSomething is defined first.

```js
function doSomething(val) {
  if (val > 150) {
    alert("You are not eligible for this reward");
  } else {
    alert("Congrats! You have just been rewarded");
  }
}

var orig_doSomething = window['doSomething'];

window['doSomething'] = function () {
  orig_doSomething.apply(null, arguments);
  // your code, or a call to your function
  alert("Wow, doSomething just finished executing with these arguments - " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="doSomething(200);">Callback gets called </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create new function with `new Function(newBody)`, but it is very-very horrible solution. Don't do that, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your function with new body using Function constructor, like so:

```
function injectToCallback(callbackFunction, newBody) {
  var entire = callbackFunction.toString();
  var args = entire.match(/^function.+\((.+)\)/);
  var body = entire.substring(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}")) + newBody;
  return new Function(args ? args[1] : "", body);
}
```

However you should notice that it's some kind of eval, so make sure you don't pass data provided by third-party things, i.e. users.

I **do not** recommend using this.